# Changing sprite texture pixels results in gigantic grey square

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 32x32 sprite that I am trying to access the pixel data of and modify.

To do this I am simply taking the sprite's texture, creating a new texture based on the old and then changing the pixel values of the new texture. I then create a new sprite with the modified texture and change the SpriteRenderer's sprite parameter to the new sprite.

However, when I actually run my script what I get is a huge grey square, easily 10x the size of the original 32x32 sprite. I'm very new to unity so I'm not sure why this is happening. Any insight would be great.

```
    private Sprite sprite;
    private Texture2D texture;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        sprite = this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
        texture = sprite.texture;
        Texture2D newTexture = modifyTexture(texture);

        SpriteRenderer sr = this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        sr.sprite = Sprite.Create(newTexture, new Rect(0, 0, newTexture.width, newTexture.height), new Vector2(0, 0), 10);
    }

    public Texture2D modifyTexture(Texture2D baseTexture)
    {
        Texture2D newTexture = new Texture2D(baseTexture.width, baseTexture.height);

        int x = 0;
        while(x < newTexture.width)
        {
            int y = 0;
            while(y < newTexture.height)
            {
                Color currentPixel = baseTexture.GetPixel(x,y);
                Color modifiedPixel = currentPixel;
                modifiedPixel.r = (float)(modifiedPixel.r + 0.10);
                modifiedPixel.b = (float)(modifiedPixel.b + 0.10);
                modifiedPixel.g = (float)(0.10);
                newTexture.SetPixel(x, y, modifiedPixel);
                y++;
            }
            x++;
        }

        Debug.Log(newTexture.GetPixel(5, 5).ToString());
        return newTexture;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After modifying pixels of a Texture, you must call the [`Apply`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) function upload the modified pixels to the graphics card.

```
public Texture2D modifyTexture(Texture2D baseTexture)
{
    Texture2D newTexture = new Texture2D(baseTexture.width, baseTexture.height);

    int x = 0;
    while (x < newTexture.width)
    {
        int y = 0;
        while (y < newTexture.height)
        {
            Color currentPixel = baseTexture.GetPixel(x, y);
            Color modifiedPixel = currentPixel;
            modifiedPixel.r = (float)(modifiedPixel.r + 0.10);
            modifiedPixel.b = (float)(modifiedPixel.b + 0.10);
            modifiedPixel.g = (float)(0.10);
            newTexture.SetPixel(x, y, modifiedPixel);
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    //Upload changes to Graphics graphics card
    newTexture.Apply();

    Debug.Log(newTexture.GetPixel(5, 5).ToString());
    return newTexture;
}
```

Comment: Calling `Apply` fixed the colouring problem, the pixels now update to their proper colours. However the new sprite is still massively bigger than the original, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The current issue is how `Sprite.Create` is used. Increase or decrease the  extrude parameter which is currently `10`. Change it to 80 or about 5 and see what happens. Also the pivot point should be `0.5f` not `0.0`. Maybe something like this: `Sprite.Create(newTexture, new Rect(0, 0, newTexture.width, newTexture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 80);` or  `Sprite.Create(newTexture, new Rect(0, 0, newTexture.width, newTexture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 3);` Tune the extrude parameter until you get what you want

Comment: What exactly does the extrude parameter do? I googled it earlier but it didn't become any clearer.

Comment: My bad. It's actually the `pixelsPerUnit` parameter not `pixelsPerUnit`. The extrude parameter comes after that but is **not** needed here and is not used by you.  The documentation states the  pixelsPerUnit is the number of pixels in the sprite that correspond to one unit in world space. See the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html) for the meaning of the rest of the parameter.